# How do I split up a line in tex file in read/write?

Tags: java, read-write

I currently have a text file that has the following:

```
1 Commercial & Enterprise  5   SLICE    59.99  IP MICRO 
2 Commercial & Enterprise  5   SLICE    59.99  MULTI-USE SWITCH
.
.
.
.
18 Government & Military   6   TCP      15.00  TCP
```

I am trying to split the line so that I can have the following:

```
Product number:  18
Category:        Government & Military
Product name:  TCP
Units in stock: 6
Price: $15.00
Total value: $90.00
Fee: $4.50
Total value: $94.50
```

I currently have the following code:

```
while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {

            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");

            p = new ActionProduct();
            add(p);
            String category = p.getCategory();
            String name = p.getName();
            category = tokens.nextToken();
            int item = p.getItem();
            double price = p.getPrice();
            int units = p.getUnits();

            while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            item = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
            price = Double.parseDouble(tokens.nextToken());
            units = Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken());
            }

            System.out.println("Category: " + category);
            System.out.println("Product number:  " + item);
            System.out.println("Product name:  " + name);
            System.out.println("Units in stock: "+ units);
            System.out.println("Price: $" + String.format("%.2f", price)); 
            System.out.println("Total value: $" + String.format("%.2f",p.value()));
            System.out.println("Fee: $" + String.format("%.2f", p.fee()));

            System.out.println("Total value: $" + String.format("%.2f", value()));
        }
```

And I am getting this output instead:

```
Category: 1 Commercial & Enterprise  5   SLICE    59.99  IP MICRO             
Product number:  0
Product name:  null
Units in stock: 0
Price: $0.00
Total value: $0.00
Fee: $0.00
Total value: $0.00
Category: 2 Commercial & Enterprise  5   SLICE    59.99  MULTI-USE SWITCH     
Product number:  0
Product name:  null
Units in stock: 0
Price: $0.00
Total value: $0.00
Fee: $0.00
Total value: $0.00
```

So my questions is…what must I do to split up the line, so that I can print each value of my textile individually?? Thanks in advance guys, would really appreciate some direction!

Here is my text file:

```
1 Commercial & Enterprise  5   SLICE    59.99  IP MICRO             
2 Commercial & Enterprise  5   SLICE    59.99  MULTI-USE SWITCH     
3 Commercial & Enterprise  4   SLICE    59.99  2100                 
4 Commercial & Enterprise  6   SLICE    59.99  IP                   
5 Commercial & Enterprise  4   HDX      45.00  HYBRID CARRIER       
6 Commercial & Enterprise  10  TRANSip  45.00  IP Technology Suite  
7 Commercial & Enterprise  5   GUI      30.00  LINK COMMAND SYS     
8 Commercial & Enterprise  5   GUI      30.00  MAUI                 
9 Commercial & Enterprise  6   RCP      20.00  RCP                  
10 Government & Military   5   SLICE    60.00  IP MICRO             
11 Government & Military   5   SLICE    60.00  MULTI-USE SWITCH     
12 Government & Military   4   SLICE    60.00  2100                 
13 Government & Military   6   SLICE    55.00  IP                   
14 Government & Military   4   HDX.C    35.00  HYBRID CARRIER       
15 Government & Military   10  TRANSip  30.00  IP Technology Suite  
16 Government & Military   5   GUI      20.00  LINK COMMAND SYS     
17 Government & Military   5   GUI      20.00  MAUI                 
18 Government & Military   6   TCP      15.00  TCP
```

Comment: humm no, I have to use a FILE.txt

Comment: ?? sorry but your reply about not being able to use regex due having to use file.txt makes no sense. Are you familiar with regular expressions and what they are used for? If so, please elaborate as to why you can't use them in say a `String#split(...)`

Comment: Also, if your text file only has 18 lines, you might as well post the whole thing. If it is simple enough, then the solution can be quite simple.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with regex. How does it work? can it be used in java?

Comment: What output are you *expecting*?

Comment: I want the output to be                                       Product number:  18
Category:        Government & Military
Product name:  TCP
Units in stock: 6
Price: $15.00
Total value: $90.00
Fee: $4.50
Total value: $94.50

Comment: Instead of just printing the entire line from the text file. Basically splitting up the line.

Comment: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.' -Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a good look at the data. Are you getting more data, or is this the only file?

If you're getting more data, you need to have some kind if spec, so you can be sure, that your parser will continue working.

If you have fixed positioning of the data, then you can use

```
String part = line.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)
```

This data file is almost with fixed positions, except when the product number increases..

Instead you can try with regex or line.split(delimitor)

Don't use regex too much before you really understand them.

If this was the only file, I think I would start with a

```
String[] parts = line.split("  ") //two spaces
```

and then parse from the string array you get.

The first part, parts[0], would contain both product number and category, but you can split that as well.

Comment: This is the only file, and the data is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to split the text based on arbitrary pattern, that is *exactly* what RegEx is for; use a RegEx parser to tokenize your input, then process the tokens as desired.

Simply put, you read the file, pass it to RegEx tokenizer, then work on the tokens (i.e. strings)

An example regex pattern for your data would be

[0-9]+[\s]+[a-zA-Z\s\Q&\E]+[\s]+[0-9]+[\s]+[a-zA-Z]+[\s]+[0-9\Q.\E]+[\s]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+

you can quickly and effectively create your pattern by using e.g.

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

further reading:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Hovercraft's solution would only work if

a) every whitespace in input is a **space** - simple use of tabs would screw everything up,
b) every field is padded with spaces to a fixed width - any failure to comply would screw evertyhing up,

so this is probably **not** what OP wants.

Comment: Yes, very true. Mine only works if the input does not change or get more complex. Deleted. 1+

Comment: Alternatively, you could just put the strings in the input into quotes and then it's a simple matter of scanf-like parsing with Scanner or StringTokenizer.

Comment: okay I will check out regex. When you say having quotes for the input, do you mean the following: "1" "Commercial & Enterprise"  "5"   "SLICE"    "59.99"  "IP MICRO" , for each line in my text file?

Comment: either that, or just for non-numeric strings - all depends on your implementation, but both would ease the pain of dealing with data input.